# Regex extension giving error "undefined is not a function"?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

In my extension, it should replace all strings like `"/jxXn1sxDJ` with `<a href="imgur.com/jxXn1sxDJx">/jxXn1sxDJx</a>`, though it says "undefined is not a function" in console. Here is my code

```
var site_content = $("body").html().replace(/(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})(?=\s)/g, '<a href="http://www.imgur.com$1">$1</a>');
$("body").html(site_content);
```

Please note that jQuery is included properly; other parts of the extension using jQuery work fine; but they do not work if I do not comment out these two lines.

Comment: do you have jQuery included? looks like `$` is undefined

Comment: yes, I have it included first in the background and under scripts in the manifest

Comment: all other jQuery functions in the extension work fine

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me like you're getting the `body` content before it is fully loaded, try placing your code after the body is completely loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var site_content = $("body").html().replace(/(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})(?=\s)/g, '<a href="http://www.imgur.com$1">$1</a>');
    $("body").html(site_content);
});
```